# Archiving vs Build

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm wondering if Archive is actually doing a build by itself? My usual steps are "Build -> Archive -> validate -> publish" but I'm wondering if the first step "Build" is actually redundant?

Reason for this question is today noticed that my app actually passed the build, but failed at archive?

Comment: Arhive builds application for you. The reason of fail can be one of the following: issue with signing, different setups for debug and release, changes after first build.

Comment: Build fails for just Release mode are often due to the Xcode build settings just being configured for Debug only and not Release (it's quite a fiddly interface).  Things like Library Search Path, Header Search Path, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, you dont required 'Build' before archiving. So, you can directly archive it(it automatically going to build it).

As per your comment - you are getting this error - while archiving = `Linker command failed library not found`

This error comes when compiler unable to find required library. So, check your `Runpath search paths`(`Library search paths` in xcode version older than iOS 12) in build settings.

As per you - You get success while building but failure while archiving - it happens only if you have kept different `Runpath search paths` for `Debug` and `Release`. See below image.

[image]

One more thing. If you wanted to reproduce samething while `Building` app, then follow this

1. Press `Command` + `Shift` + `<` (this will open edit scheme)
2. You will be on below screen :

[image]

3. Here, Change build configuration for 'Run' from `Debug` to `Release`.

After making above change, when you run the app, it will build exactly same as `archive` case, so if you are build getting failed while archiving, then it must be failing now, otherwise will work fine.